# how to convert table columns to one new column

Tags: azure, azure-data-explorer, kql

i´m having a table in Azure Data Explorer like this:

| OperationsId | name | resultCode | duration |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1234 | httprequest1234 | 200 | 79,3 |
| 5678 | httprequest5678 | 200 | 11,5 |

I would like to now summarize now by OperationsID, but than having all remaining items which corresponds to this operationsID in a new column like this:

| OperationsId | Details |
| --- | --- |
| 1234 | {"name": "httprequest1234", "resultcode":200, "duration":79,3, ....} |
| 5678 | {"name": "httprequest5678", "resultcode":200, "duration":11,5, ....} |

doesn´t have to be JSON, but is there a way to convert a table or multiple columns of a table to a new column?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
datatable (OperationsId:long, name:string, resultCode:int, duration:real)
[
    1234 ,"httprequest1234" ,200 ,79.3
   ,5678 ,"httprequest5678" ,200 ,11.5
]
| project OperationsId, Details = bag_remove_keys(pack_all(), dynamic(["OperationsId"]))
```

| OperationsId | Details |
| --- | --- |
| 1234 | {"name":"httprequest1234","resultCode":200,"duration":79.3} |
| 5678 | {"name":"httprequest5678","resultCode":200,"duration":11.5} |

[Fiddle](https://dataexplorer.azure.com/clusters/help/databases/Samples?query=H4sIAAAAAAAAA1WOzQqCQBSF9z7FxdUIg/iTWUKr2rTqAURk1ItNjo7NXAOhh0%20JwO5Z3cN34GsELakUAruNaARJPdhrkyk9tBwG0WNmycj1MWgnRWfdYCYH4tBMXzwzKJTn5A4sF0bxDrh7JxoNPie0tDYu8CgIgKdHP14xnuzTwz%202Nj8sDP3EKZw3jEY/sCbYqnG4IAmpLJygEm1psNcvLDucLRtF3ZVCKeYtevNiL2uWu9u1W3jeBwEbayX0AAAA)

Comment: thanks, this is something I already know David, BUT how do I do this with values from the existing table instead of doing it manually?

Comment: ok, gave it a try... now I indeed get my expected result, but the operationsId in the first column appears to be there multiple time instead of just once! Is there a way to have just one operations ID and all nested rows with the same opsID in the Details column? [ADXTestQuery](www.shorturl.at/ijlX2)

Comment: This answers your original question. If you have a modified question, you should use a new post. Make sure to provide a matching sample data  + required results (pay attention to how do multiple rows getting merged to a single row). P.S. please make sure to delete the comments and accept the answer.